# StringBuilder что лучше использовать для записи в файл?

Tags: c#

Посоветуйте, как правильно записывать в файл текст из `StringBuilder`?

Начитался кучей советов, что якобы не важно что использовать, главное на разных версия .Net по своему можно использовать запись:

Например:

( для старой версии .Net) - Используется `StreamWriter`,

( для новой версии .Net) - Используется: `File.WriteAllText(PathToFile, StringBuilderText);`

Comment: Какого размера у вас файл? Если небольшой, то совсем неважно какой метод, главное что бы работал.

Comment: @Zergatul,размер файла 2 мб, максимум 4.

Comment: @Zergatul, А для большого использовать `StreamWriter` ? (примерно сколько нужно размера для его использования ) ?

Comment: @GooliveR, используйте `File.WriteAllText()` для любых случаев. Если он не сможет записать, то и другой метод не сможет, но здесь преимущество - простота использования. Он сам откроет файл, запишет данные и правильно освободит ресурсы.

Comment: Если все данные для записи уже в памяти, то не имеет значения. Проще всего, как написал @Андрей, и ошибок меньше. А если данные генерируются или читаются из другого файла, то чтение и запись через поток может уменьшить текущий расход памяти программы, а в некоторых случаях и производительность. Это не зависит от версии фреймворка.

Comment: @rdorn, Буду знать, спасибо.